# How can I call this range for all available values?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, data-structures

I'm calling two columns, latitude and longitude from Google sheets. The below statements successfully plot the 5th longitude and latitude points, but that's all. I don't know what the 10 does in this case. I can change the 5's to 9's and have them plot the 9th set of coordinates. However, I want all available points plotted (multiple markers). Much like the enumerate method i've used in Python (included below).

```
  Iterable _markers = Iterable.generate(10, (index) {
    LatLng latLngMarker = LatLng(latitudelist[5], longitudelist[5]);
    return Marker(markerId: MarkerId("Test $index"), position: latLngMarker);
  });
```

Python:

```
for x,y in enumerate(latitude):
    kml.newpoint(name=pointname[x], coords=[(longitude[x], latitude[x])])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < latitudelist.length; i++) {
      var markerIdVal = generateIds();
      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal.toString());
      final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(
          latitudelist[i],
          longitudelist[i],
        ),
        //infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: name[i].place, snippet: name[i].region), //optional
      );
```